# Can not able to execute the query in MYSQL via python

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Hi I'm new to the PYTHON and MYSQL. I'm trying to update the data base using the python where I'm taking user input and trying to update into the database.
Can any buddy help me in this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\Anaconda3\envs\MyTest\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 148, in send_plain
    self.sock.sendall(packet)
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\Anaconda3\envs\MyTest\lib\ssl.py", line 1037, in sendall
    return super().sendall(data, flags)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/YGIN/PycharmProjects/MyTest/BankApplication.py", line 181, in <module>
    c1.customer_closing_account()
  File "C:/Users/YGIN/PycharmProjects/MyTest/BankApplication.py", line 146, in customer_closing_account
    dbq.delete_cust_account(self.account_no)
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\PycharmProjects\MyTest\DB_queryies.py", line 71, in delete_cust_account
    my_cursor.execute(mysqlinsertquery, recordstodel)
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\Anaconda3\envs\MyTest\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\Anaconda3\envs\MyTest\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 590, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\Anaconda3\envs\MyTest\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 344, in _send_cmd
    packet_number, compressed_packet_number)
  File "C:\Users\YGIN\Anaconda3\envs\MyTest\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 151, in send_plain
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 10038 An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```